# Put event on this within jquery plugin

Tags: jquery

I want to create a jquery plugin for long-short touch detected; I dont understand, how can I put `.on` event on `this` within plugin in init method. Please, help me

```
(function($) 
{
// default
var defaults = 
{ 
touchduration: 200,
touch: function(){ alert("Touch"); return false; },
longtouch: function(){ alert("Long touch"); return false; }
},
timerInterval,
leftTimer,
_this;

var methods = 
{
    init: function(params) 
    {
        var _this = this,
        options = $.extend({}, defaults, params),
        init = $(this).data('fctouch');

        if(init) 
        return this;
        else 
        {
            $(this).data('options', options);

/* Here is my trouble place */

            $(document)
            .on('touchstart', this, function() { touchstart() } )
            .on('touchend', this, function() { touchend() } );

            return $(this);
        }
    },

    destroy: function() 
    {
        $(_this).off().removeData();
    }
};

function timer(interval) 
{
    interval--;
    leftTimer = interval;

    if(interval >= 0) 
    {
        timerInterval = setTimeout(function() 
        {
            timer(interval);
        });
    } 
    else 
    {
        $(_this).data("options").longtouch();
        touchend();
    }
}


function touchstart() 
{
    timer($(_this).data("options").touchduration);
}


function touchend() 
{
    if(leftTimer >= 100)
    $(_this).data("options").touch();

    clearTimeout(timerInterval);
}

$.fn.fctouch = function(method)
{
    if(methods[method]) 
    {

        return methods[method].apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
    } 
    else if(typeof method === 'object' || !method) 
    {
        return methods.init.apply(this, arguments);
    } 
    else 
    {

        $.error( 'Method "' +  method + '" doesnt found' );
    }
};
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Note that `this` in main plugin function is already jQuery object... returned from  `$(selector)`

Comment: That's why you see `return this.each(function...` in a lot of plugins